# Select records which the values of the field are the same

Tags: c#, linq

[image]

I have a list getting from the SQLite database like this:

```
var decisions = _db.decisions.Where(x => x.folder_id == Folder.Id).ToList();
```

If the values of the 'rec_no' field in this list are the same, I would like to output these records in a foreach loop and remaining records to a separate foreach loop. But I have no idea about it.

**EDIT 1:** I want to output 'rec_no' is 13 in a foreach loop and others are in seperated foreach loop which 'folder_id' is 87.

**EDIT 2:** In the example below, is it possible to output 'rec_no' is 13 ones a loop, 'rec_no' is 5 ones a loop, and the others a loop?

[image]

Comment: Input sample along with expected result are welcome

Comment: Do you mean all records in decisions list having same value for rec_no property should be in a separate list and rest of them in a different list. Thats GroupBy rec_no in a loop.

Comment: It's not clear from the sample and your description exactly what you want. Are you looking for duplicates?

Comment: Sorry, I am developing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this

```
var decisions = _db.decisions.Where(x => x.folder_id == Folder.Id).ToList();

var dupKeys = decisions.GroupBy(x => x.RecNo)
              .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
              .Select(y => y.Key)
              .ToList();

var dupList = decistions.Where(x => dupKeys.Contains(x.RecNo)).ToList();

var restDecisions = decisions.Except(dupList);
```

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu- Would it be possible to look edit 2 for me?

Comment: I asked again in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64799611/1827846