# Output records which the values of the field are the same

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This topic is may be dublicated. I asked in a different scenario under [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64150691/select-records-which-the-values-of-the-field-are-the-same) and it is answered by [Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64150811/1827846). When I edited my topic like this and asked again, Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu said I should ask this in a new topic. So I had to ask the question in a new topic.

Here is data schema example:

[image]

I have a list getting from the SQLite database like this:

```
var decisions = _db.decisions.Where(x => x.CAT_ID == Cat.Id).ToList();
```

If the values of the `REC_ID` field in this list are the same, I would like to output these records in foreach loops and remaining records to a separate foreach loop. For example in the list above, `REC_ID` 13 ones are a in a loop, `REC_ID` 5 ones are a in a loop, `REC_ID` 7 ones are a in a loop and the others are in a last loop.

Edit from comment:

I want to separate those with more than one same value and the remainder.In our example, IDs' `{1, 2, 3}` `{4, 5}` `{6, 7}` and `{8, 9}` should be seperated.

Comment: so basically you would like to separate all different `REC_ID` values? did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @MongZhu - No. I want to separate those with more than one same value and the remainder.In our example, IDs' `{1, 2, 3}` `{4, 5}` `{6, 7}` and `{8, 9}` should be seperated. Because they all have the same CAT_ID.

Comment: this is exactly what my code does. I will edit it and add an examplary programm with output to show you

Comment: ok I understood you better now, I think :) you want the remainder flatten in a single list. I made a second edit and showed how you can flatten the groupings. Have a look

Comment: @MongZhu - Thank you very much. I am trying now and I will let you know the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to separate those with more than one same value and the remainder.In our example, IDs' `{1, 2, 3}` `{4, 5}` `{6, 7}` and `{8, 9}` should be seperated.

Ok then you can group by the `REC_ID` and check wether the `Count()` of the group is larger than 1 (giving you "more than one same value") or equal to 1 (giving you "the remainder"), the latter has to be flattened again to get them into the same collection back together

```
List<IGrouping<int, MyClass>> recIdGroupsMultipleEntries = decisions.GroupBy(x => x.REC_ID)
                                                               .Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToList();
List<MyClass> recIdSingleEntries = list.GroupBy(x => x.REC_ID)
                                             .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                                             .SelectMany(flat => flat).ToList();
```

Here is an examplary programm with output to show this:

```
void Main()
{
    List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {   
        list.Add(new MyClass { ID = i, TITLE = $"title {i}", CAT_ID = 81});
    }

    list[0].REC_ID = 13;
    list[1].REC_ID = 13;
    list[2].REC_ID = 13;
    list[3].REC_ID = 5;
    list[4].REC_ID = 5;
    list[5].REC_ID = 7;
    list[6].REC_ID = 7;
    list[7].REC_ID = 1;
    list[8].REC_ID = 2;


    List<IGrouping<int, MyClass>> recIdGroupsMultipleEntries = list.GroupBy(x => x.REC_ID).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToList();
    List<MyClass> recIdSingleEntries = list.GroupBy(x => x.REC_ID)
                                                                 .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                                                                 .SelectMany(flat => flat).ToList();
    
    foreach (var group in recIdGroupsMultipleEntries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"REC_ID: {group.Key} || {string.Join(", ", group.Select(x => x.ID))}");  
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"REC_ID: {recIdSingleEntries.Select(x => x.REC_ID).First()} || {string.Join(", ", recIdSingleEntries.Select(x => x.ID))}");

}
```

Output:

> REC_ID: 13 || 1, 2, 3
> REC_ID: 5 || 4, 5
> REC_ID: 7 || 6, 7
> REC_ID: 1 || 8, 9